# trouble installing MySQL on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: mysql

When trying the following:

```
apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

I'm getting the following response:

```
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.6.postinst: line 132: logger: command not found
2015-11-08 18:30:37 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-11-08 18:30:37 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.27-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) starting as process 1409 ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.6.postinst: line 210: logger: command not found
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.95-1) ...
Setting up mysql-client (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.6; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (219-7ubuntu4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.6
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm running as root.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm new to this. I've found somewhat similar posts on this site but just can't find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.6.postinst: line 210: logger: command not found
```

That is your error.  The postinst script calls `logger` which will output something to syslog.

Make sure it's installed first - `sudo apt-get install bsdutils`

Comment: It says E: Unable to locate package logger

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction. Apparently I had to reinstall something called 'bsdutils' which contained the logger I think. It's working now! Thanks, been at it for a while now!

Comment: @Hees1989 see my edit, i found the package name.  And, you found it, great!  If the system lets you, you can upvote to indicate it helped, since you already accepted it as the answer.